# Is this expression clear and idiomatic, "what is the value N/(2<sup>k</sup>) at least should be"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I asked a [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/115064/109866) just now.

> Thanks for your answer. In your context, what is the value N/(2<sup>k</sup>) at least should be?

Is this expression clear and idiomatic?

All the discussion is in the field of Artificial Intelligence, more specifically, Machine Learning.

Why this value should vary?

Because N stands for the number of samples, different datasets may have different N, so is the `k`

So, neither `N` nor `k` is a fixed value, neither is `N/(2<sup>k</sup>)`.

`N/(2<sup>k</sup>)` varies in a range. What I asked there is the minimum value of `N/(2<sup>k</sup>)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is neither clear nor idiomatic as it stands.

A clear question would be:

> What is the value N/(2k)

While I am not familiar with the field you describe, I would shy away from the word **context**. Subject to guidance from experts, I would prefer:

> Based on your datasets, what is the value N/(2k)

The phrase: **at least should be** is simply confusing. It's hard to know what you are trying to say. Do you mean **what is the minimum value**? **What is the least possible value?**

You need to clarify the meaning of this phrase.